# Magento, automatically assign newsletter subscribers to newsletter subscriber group

Tags: newsletter, group

I have created the newsletter subscriber group on customer group, so I can apply discount to them, is there anyway to make it automatic, if someone subscribe to newsletter he/she automatically assign to newsletter subscribers group that had created?

Comment: hello you there. please accept the answer if it helped you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is listen to the event for customer save before `customer_save_before`, check to see if they are subscribing to the newsletter, If they are then you can update the group assigned to the customer and they will be saved into this new group.

The attribute for newsletter subscription is `is_subscribed` and you can call `setCustomerGroupId` on the customer object to update the group.